# Azure RM & Powershell (Service Name)

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

I have writen a script that provisions the VM in AzureRM, I now need to access the VM and add the endpoints, using something like the below

```
    $VMLocalAdminUser = $DeployCredentials.Username
    $VMLocalAdminSecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $deployCredentials.Password -AsPlainText -Force
    $Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($VMLocalAdminUser, $VMLocalAdminSecurePassword);
```

New-AzureRmVm 
    `-ResourceGroupName $hostMachine.ResourceGroup`
    -Name $($machine.VirtualMachineName) 
    `-ImageName $($image.ImageName)`
    -Location $hostMachine.Location `
    -Credential $Credential

```
  $vm = Get-AzureRMVM -ServiceName "" -Name $machine.VirtualMachineName

  $vm | Add-AzureEndpoint -Name "File Sharing 1" -Protocol "tcp" -PublicPort ###-LocalPort ###
  $vm | Add-AzureEndpoint -Name "File Sharing 2" -Protocol "tcp" -PublicPort ### -LocalPort ### 
  $vm | Add-AzureEndpoint -Name "RemoteDesktop" -Protocol "tcp" -PublicPort #### -LocalPort ####
```

I am now trying to work out how I do this in AzureRM, main question being what is the ServiceName where and how do I find it to add it to the above.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get-AzureRMVM shouldnt require -servicename as below from microsoft

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/get-azurermvm?view=azurermps-6.4.0